# Can't get data out of .mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, gridview

I created a project a while ago and transferred it to my other computer, and now it's stopped working. I can't manage to fill the grid with the data from the `.mdf`.

I have struggled a while with this problem and I can't manage to solve it. I would appreciate if someone here could download the `.rar` and help me solve this problem.

http://www.filefactory.com/file/3wabxfsyxign/n/CDapplikation_uppgift_rar

Answer (score 3):

`.mdf` are **SQL Server** data files; for working with those files, you must have some version (other than Compact Edition) of SQL Server installed

So to get this data out:

- check to see what version of SQL Server you have installed
- fire up the management tool, e.g. SQL Server Management Studio (possibly the Express version which you can find by searching on Google or Bing and download for free from Microsoft)
- attach the `.mdf` file to the SQL Server under a logical name, so that you can use it
- now you can access it using raw ADO.NET or Entity Framework or whatever other data access technology you wish to use